# ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS for lower than 22 API

Tags: android, android-notifications

When I want to open notification settings on pre-22 API I gets alert in AS

> Field requires API level 22 (current min is 19): android.provider.Settings#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS

But I still need to open such settings. By the way, on Nexus 4 it works without any errors.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS) **field** as been added in the API 22. But the **value** can be used on lower API.

> Constant Value: "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"

However it highlights that this field is linked to methods that could not be implemented yet, e.g. if the action has extras, they may be null, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.